# Change "field" key type in MUI DataGrid's GridColDef interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datagrid

The default type of GridColDef's `field` key is `string`. I want to assign an array of specific strings to it. Is there a way to make it work?

I tried with `Array<Omit<GridColDef, 'field'> & {field: 'name' | 'id'}>` and using the generic `Array<GridColDef<{field: 'name' | 'id'}>>` but neither worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can always use type assertion (`[] as unknown as string`) but that's just working against the types that help you to prevent possible runtime errors.  I'm not familiar with `GridColDef's` field  but there probably is a reason the type is restricted to `string` only.